# Extend project-level dictionary (of words) using a custom file

Tags: python

In PyCharm we can add certain words to the project-level dictionary by right clicking on it and subsequently pressing on *"Save '{word}' to project-level dictionary"*:

[image]

However, when I start a new project, how can I import this list using a more generic methods. Some of my teammates might be working with Visual Studio and thus not have this ability.

Is there a Python way of handling word dictionaries in the environment?

Thinking that ideally it would be something like the file `requirements.txt`, but instead for instance `words.txt` that I place in the root of my repository.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *need* to? To my knowledge this has no effect on the actual code, it's just an English-language spellchecker for your comments and variable names, right?

Comment: Well it bothers me that it highlights these "wrong" or "unknown" words in my editor. I do not want to disable the spell check, but only allow certain words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in Pycharm:

1. Create a file ‘words.dic’
2. Open settings > search for “Spelling”
3. Add your file (+) to the project dictionaries